# Android Slide Fragment don't load all

Tags: android, android-fragments, slide

I am working on Fragments to do a simple 3 pages application, with slide between page.

But For now, I Have 3 Fragments, but the application slide only with de 2 and 3.

It must do `1` -> `2` -> `3`, but It do `3` -> `2` -> `3`. If you know what I try to say.

This is my code

```
public class main extends Activity {



public static SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public static Boolean init = true;


static ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   [...]
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private static int ARG_NUMBER = 0;



    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ARG_NUMBER = sectionNumber;
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = new View(this.getActivity());

   // THE PROBLEM SHOULD COME FROM HERE

            switch (ARG_NUMBER) {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
                    break;
            }


        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

So, if anyone has an idea ... Thanks !

EDIT :

```
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: post code of `SectionsPagerAdapter`

Comment: I've add it in the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should `use arguments` of fragment `instead of` setting `ARG_NUMBER  = sectionNumber`

your code should look something like this:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private int ARG_NUMBER = 0;



    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = new View(this.getActivity());

         ARG_NUMBER = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, 0);

            switch (ARG_NUMBER) {
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);
                    break;
            }


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Note: Use if-else ladder if Switch case does not allow for non-constant value.

Comment: How does that solve the problem of having a wrong fragment in the adapter ? Also, you use 0 as the default value for getInt whereas there is no default case in the switch statement to handle that value. Secondly, doing getArguments().getInt doesn't check for null, but the Fragment could very well instantiated with its empty constructor, so why not using the interface method suggested by Google in the official documentation about Fragments so it throws a meaningful exception instead of a NPE ?

Comment: @2Dee: here, fragment is gonna be part of `ViewPager` so there is no possibilities of having such scenarios. And I've suggested about arguments only,see my answer.it is based upon that change only in comparison with existing code provided by OP.and you might face such things when you are dealing with independent fragments. anyways, feel free to edit or post your answer.